# Difference between MS CRM 4.0 and CRM 2011 platform

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I work with other CRM and now want to learn Microsoft CRM (programming and customization). I have found one book "Programming Microsoft CRM  4.0". Is it useful for CRM 2011 platform learning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CRM 2011 User Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/A/D2AA0691-7EF5-4CCB-843E-CCF13ADBD9AA/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2011_User%27s_Guide.doc) is available to download, as well as available [programming reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328282.aspx) and [Client-Side Programming Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328255.aspx)